CSFML Background not loading
I'm trying to learn how to use CSFML. And i created this basic window:

my_window_t *init_window(void)
{
    my_window_t *temp = malloc(sizeof(my_window_t));
    sfTexture *texture = sfTexture_createFromFile("background.jpeg", NULL);
    sfSprite *sprite = sfSprite_create();

    temp->font = font;
    temp->bg_sprite = sprite;
    return temp;
}

void main(void)
{
    sfVideoMode mode = {960, 540, 32};
    sfEvent event;
    my_window_t *screen = init_window();
    sfRenderWindow *window;

    window = sfRenderWindow_create(mode, "Test_CSFML", sfClose, NULL);
    sfRenderWindow_setPosition(window, (sfVector2i){0, 0});
    sfRenderWindow_setFramerateLimit(window, 60);
    while (sfRenderWindow_isOpen(window)) {
        while (sfRenderWindow_pollEvent(window, &event))
            main_event(window, &event, screen);
        sfRenderWindow_clear(window, sfBlack);
        sfRenderWindow_drawSprite(window, screen->bg_sprite, 0);
        sfRenderWindow_display(window);
    }
    sfRenderWindow_destroy(window);
}


Here is my structure:
typedef struct my_window_t {
    sfSprite *bg_sprite;
    sfSoundBuffer *music_buffer;
    sfSound *music_sound;
    sfFont *font;
}my_window_t;


All the other element in my structure are loaded in another part
I tried to change the name of the texture, switched with a png file but nothing is loading and I just have a black screen.
I didnt find anything in the CSFML Documentation

You are creating a Sprite and a a texture but you never keep the texture in a variable or add it to the sprite.
The sprite you create dont have any texture, in order to fix that i recommend doing something like this.
typedef struct my_window_t {
    sfSprite *bg_sprite;
    sfTexture *bg_texture
    sfSoundBuffer *music_buffer;
    sfSound *music_sound;
    sfFont *font;
}my_window_t;

my_window_t *init_window(void)
{
    my_window_t *temp = malloc(sizeof(my_window_t));
    sfTexture *texture = sfTexture_createFromFile("background.jpeg", NULL);
    sfSprite *sprite = sfSprite_create();

    temp->font = font;
    //Store in the structure in order to destroy it after
    temp->bg_texture = texture;
    //Adding a texture to the sprite
    sfSprite_setTexture(sprite, temp->bg_text, 0);
    temp->bg_sprite = sprite;
    return temp;
}


With this modification, it supposed to work, if you have any other problem i will be happy to help you.
Also check the CFML documentation, you will have more information that in the SFML documentation

Thanks, can you give me more information about destroy, do i need to destroy everything?

In CSFML everything that you create need to be detroyed, you already destroy the window. I recommend a function that destroy every texture, sprite, sfFont, sfSoundBuffer that you'll call once the window is closed
